# builtins.AttributeError AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'Dictwriter'

Tags: python, csv

testing https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter function and get back with error per below and attached with sameple code.

```
builtins.AttributeError AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'Dictwriter'
```

Running on Python 3.7.1rc1

Any one know the reason here?

Code per below:

```
import csv

# create the csv writer object
with open(file_output, 'w+') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    csv_writer = csv.Dictwriter(csv_file,fieldnames=fieldnames)

    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DictWriter has a capital W. 
Try replacing your line with,

```
...
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file,fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

A way to debug an error like this would be to run it in a REPL, run python3.

You can then import `csv` and explore the dict module to make sure that you are using the correct function/ class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed my problem here : )